# Using two for-loops

Tags: c#, for-loop

This is an easy question but I'm still learning this language.

How we can write program that has parameters so that if the the number is 5, it will write

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I can do this:

```
*
*
*
*
```

Using this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = " ";

    for (int count = 0; count < numericUpDown1.Value; count++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < numericUpDown1.Value; count)
        {
            message += "*" + "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need the second `for`-loop, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Is this homework? If it is, please tag it as such. =)

Comment: Oh, and there seems to be some question about which language you mean - C# or Java?

Comment: You might also want to investigate the StringBuilder class if you're trying to learn idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 10):

if that's not a conceptual homework it would be much easier to solve this way:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(new string('*',i));
```

Comment: thanks ;) but consider there's a little mistake...actually the index is not starting from 0 but 1 and it should loop till i<=n. It was just to make a cool shot :)

Comment: The OP is at his very start of its journey to learn CSharp. The @Gamecat answer seems more appropriated, even if your is more efficient.

Comment: You are right. I mean there are several ways to implement such a logic and another one I can think of is using iteration just once and recursion avoiding the second loop. It would be another few code lines shot. But it's just for the sake of aesthetic. My answer just gave the chance to know about a smart way to repeat chars on a string. That's enough for me and sharing knowledge is what makes big this place. I was rewarded far too much today for such a simple reply :P

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops (see note).

First (a) counts from 1 to 5.

Second (b) counts from 1 to a and adds a "*" each time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = " ";

    for (int count = 0; count < numericUpDown1.Value; count++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < count; m++)
        {
            message += "*";
        }
        message += "\r\n"
    }
}
```

**Note** You can do it with one for loop. But personally I think the two loop version is clearer.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line = "";
    string message = " ";

    for (int count = 0; count < numericUpDown1.Value; count++)
    {
       line += "*";
       message += "\r\n" + line;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an opportunity to present the `Environment.NewLine` variable to the OP.

Comment: @Steve B the question was first untagged, then java, then c# ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";
    for (int count = 0; count < numericUpDown1.Value; count++)
    {
            for (int m = 0; m <=count ; m++)
            {
                    message += "*" ;
            }
            message += "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo do not need two for-loops, try this instead

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "";

    for (int count = 1; count < numericUpDown1.Value + 1; count++)
    {
         message += "".PadLeft(count,'*') + Environment.NewLine;      
    }
}
```

Comment: "".PadLeft is a little bit obfuscated as compared to new string('*', n)

Comment: Doesn't mean it's not helpful - obviously OP is learning, and this question has given the opportunity to clearly show the multitude of different ways of solving that singular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just another way to do it for learning:

```
  private static void PrintStars(int num)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```